# Activex control not working on other systems vb6

Tags: vb6, activex

I created a simple activex control on vb6 and embeded on a web page.

```
<OBJECT ID="UserControl1"
CLASSID="CLSID:B592C5C2-5D36-4053-ADF6-910DC98A3895"
CODEBASE="http://192.168.2.100/test/package/support/mtest.ocx">
</OBJECT>
```

the activex control is a just a button,it works well on my system (its created on my system),but not on any other system.

Whats wrong with me ?

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751971.aspx)

Comment: @MarkHall Thanks for your valuable Link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object tag renders in this manner:
1.  First, look up the classid in the registry.  If not found, download and install ocx.  If found, check version against version attribute in object tag, if any.  (you don't have one.)  If version attribute in tag is higher than local version, download and reinstall.
2.  Run the ocx and render the control in the page.

Now, the most usual impediment to getting this done is that nobody wants to install ActiveX files, because it's too easy to put malicious code in them.  Most sites simply don't allow them to be loaded.  Try manually installing and registering your ocx on another system (look up RegSvr32.exe if you don't know about it).  If you get it installed, and your page then runs the way it should, you've got your answer.

I'd first do this with a target machine, to rule out this as a possibility.